# Trouble doing a plot in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Im working with a dataframe that have the participants of the olimpic games, I wanted to plot the amount of female participants along the different years to see if there has been and increased amount of female participants over time, the problem is that Im having trouble at plotting it since I dont really manage myself in working with dataframes and pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import plotly
import plotly.express as px

mpl.rcParams['agg.path.chunksize'] = 10000
df = pd.read_csv("athlete_events.csv")

z= (df['Sex'] == 'F')
plt.plot(df['Year'],z, color='red',marker='o')
plt.xlabel('Year',fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Females per year', fontsize=14)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
#df.plot(x= 'Years', y= z ,kind='hist',figsize[10,10], fontsize=15)
```

This was my first try, and obviously didnt work since it couldn't be so easy, but I don really know what steps to take since I havent done anything like this before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the filtering of the dataframe might be the issue, we will first filter only `Sex == 'F'`, group by Year and get a `count()` to have the count of females per year. please try with the following:

```
data = df[df['Sex'] == 'F'].groupby('Year')['Sex'].count()
plt.plot(data.index,data['Sex'], color='red',marker='o')
plt.xlabel('Year',fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Females per year', fontsize=14)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: It thows me the folowing error now:
 ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (271116,) and (74522, 15)

Comment: Now it worked!, Thanks a lot you are a hero